# Scala: Operator Pattern Matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, operators

Is it possible in Scala to do pattern matching with an operator?
I want to input a tuple, for example `("Hello World", +)` or `("Good Afternoon", /)` and do different actions for different operators, like:

```
mytuple match {
  case (SomeRegex(str), +) => println(str + " the same")
  case (SomeRegex(str), /) => println(str + " but different")
}
```

How can I correctly do this? I don't care what the operators do, I just want them as a kind of *environment*.

Maybe even passing the char `+`or `/` along is considered best practice, but I hardly believe it.

Answer (score 1):

Where would the `+` and `*` be coming from?  And what would the type of `mytuple` be?

Depending on your answer to those, this might be a reasonable answer.

The language doesn't really expose `*` and `+` as objects (at least not in the way it seems like you're aiming for).

```
sealed trait Op
case object `+` extends Op
case object `*` extends Op
// ...
```

With those definitions in hand...

```
def dispatch(mytuple: (String, Op)): Unit =
  mytuple match {
    case (SomeRegex(str), `+`) => println(str + " the same")
    case (SomeRegex(str), `*`) => println(str + " but different")
    case _ => ()
  }
```

You can treat `+` and `*` (or any other string that the parser might have treated otherwise: `def` `type` `class` `some identifier with spaces`) as regular identifiers by wrapping them in `'s.